# How to convert an HTML Collection into Array in Firefox and IE

Tags: javascript, arrays, cross-browser, getelementsbytagname, htmlcollection

I need to convert an array-like object into a real array. I'm using getElementsByTagName to get the list of elements.

```
var tablerow = document.body.getElementsByTagName('tr');
console.log(tablerow);

var tablerowArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(tablerow)
console.log(tablerowArr);
```

In Chrome, `tablerowArr` correctly converts into an array with the same number of items. However in Firefox and IE, it has 0 items.

What am I doing incorrectly?

Note: I am doing this so I can use

```
tablerowArr.forEach(function (value, i) { ...do stuff }
```

Comment: Why not `Array.prototype.forEach.call(tablerow, function(row, i){...})`? Then if you've included a polyfill for *forEach* for IE 8 the code won't throw an error like it will for *slice*.

Comment: Voting to close as can't reproduce. Converting collections using *slice* works fine in all browsers other than IE8, which barfs if *this* isn't a native object (the HTMLCollection returned by *getElementsByTagName* is a host object).

Comment: Something strange is happening. When I make a JS bin with my code - it works cross browser. But in my local app it doesn't. I'll have to troubleshoot and see what is interferreing with it. http://jsbin.com/kirati/

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was using WebComponents.JS for  HTML5 Imports, and this was was causing an error on Firefox and IE. I disabled the HTML5 imports and put the html directly on the page and it works fine.